# Show $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ on every line through the origin but not is not continuous at $(0,0)$ for specific function - verificationn

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & |y| > x^{2}\ \text{or}\ y = 0 \\
1, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

Show $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ on every line through the origin but not is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Attempt:

Observe that a line is described as $y = cx$. Also for $|x| < 1$, $|cx| > x^{2}$ is always true. As a result of this we will always be in the case where $|y| > x^{2}$.

Choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Observe that $|x-0|, |y-0| \leq \|(x,y) - (0,0)\| < \delta$.

With this in place:

$$\|f(x,y) - f(0,0)\| = |cx - 0| = |c||x| < |c|\delta = |c| \frac{\epsilon}{|c|} = \epsilon$$

Therefore along any line through the origin $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous.

The reason $\mathbf{f}$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ is because in the case $|y| < x^{2}$, $f(x,y) = 1$. So the limits will never be equal.

End of proof

**Issue:** The concern I have with my proof is how I showed continuity in the linear case. I don't know if I expressed the right idea. I visually see what is happening. In words: I know any linear path I take towards the origin will be the within $|y| > x^{2}$ case. As such the function should always equal $0$.

But when drawing pictures and looking at the domain, the $\delta$ that I choose will have to depend on the level of the slope of my line, i.e the $c$ value.

So my main issue is that the function is defined as the original one at the top, but I used a different function in showing the epsilon statement. I'm trying to liken the idea to say a situation where for example we:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{x}$$

If I take the limit $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along the path $y = cx$, I would put that $y$ value in my expression and take the limit or in particular to this situation I could find a $\delta$ to show it is continuous along lines only. I'm not sure I'm communicating the same idea correctly in the above case. Perhaps I'm over complicating it. (I'm just using this as an example for what I'm doing above) Thoughts?

Comment: Try $x=\sqrt{|y|}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg overall I agree yes if I were showing that the third function is not continuous at $0$ I could take that path. I was just using this as an idea of what I am trying to accomplish in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

Firstly it is not true that $\vert cx\vert > x^2$ for $\vert x\vert < 1$. Take $x$ close to $1$ and $c$ close to zero and the inequality won't hold.

Secondly, you wrote : $$ \vert f(x,y) - f(0,0) \vert = \vert cx - 0\vert.$$

This equality is incorrect since $f(x,y)$ is either $1$ or $0$. Where does this $cx$ come from ?

Anyway these problems can be fixed.

We want to prove that $$ \lim_{(x,y =cx) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$$
for any value of $c$. Clearly this is true for $c = 0$.

Suppose that $c\neq 0.$ Notice that $ \vert cx\vert > \vert x\vert^2 \iff \vert x\vert ^2- \vert c \vert \vert x \vert < 0 \iff \vert x\vert \in (0, \vert c \vert)$.

Let $\epsilon >0$.

$$\Vert (x,cx)\Vert < \delta := \vert c \vert \implies \vert x \vert < \vert c \vert  \implies f(x,cx) = 0 \implies \Vert f(x,cx)- f(0,0)\Vert = 0 < \epsilon.$$

Hence the limit is $0$ along the lines $y = cx$.

The fact that $\delta$ depends on the slope is not a problem. In fact we expect $\delta$ to depend on $c$ since we're taking a limit along a path which is dependent on $c$.

Comment: Thank you for this. I realize I need to just take what is given to me and work with it instead of trying to complicate things and create made up functions.

Comment: Also th eidea of $|x| = \sqrt{x^{2}}$ coming up so often I need to get comfortable with it

Comment: I actually have a question. When I was working out things I got: $\|(x,cx)\| = \sqrt{x^{2}+c^{2}x^{2}} = |x|\sqrt{1+|c|} <|c|$ after a bunch of algebra.  Is the whole inequality true because we would have $|x| < |x|\sqrt{1+|c|} <|c|$ and if we are considering points close to $0$ then multiplying any constant by $|x|$ will make that value less than $|c|$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question :/ Most of the equalities you've written don't hold for any given $x,c$. You can see this by seeing $c = 0$ then you would have the inequality $\vert x \vert < 0$ which is impossible. The inequalities and equalities you've written aren't true for all numbers so you should specify some conditions on $x,c$ if you want them to be correct.

Comment: I see what you mean. Like you said I have to specify the conditions for which the inequalities will be correct. That means the inequalities would not hold for values outside of these conditions. We got the set of conditions by the manipulation you did above showing $|x| \in (0,|c|)$. But as a test, I tried a value $c = 1$ to test the inequality I wrote out. I let $|x| = 0.9$ and as you may see my inequality I wrote was not satisfied. But if $\|(x,cx)\| = \sqrt{x^{2}+c^{2}x^{2}} = |x|\sqrt{1+|c|} <|c|$ how is $|x| < |c|$ being shown?

Comment: I think the thing is I'm trying to explicitly see $|x| < |c|$ occur from the expression $\|(x,cx)\| < |c|$.............and it just dawned on me from reverse triangle inequality:  $|c| > \|(x,cx)\| > |x| \ \text{and}\  |cx|$ individually so my inequality is satisfied...and I may proceed. Thanks for the nudge

Comment: @dc3rd Firstly $\sqrt{x^2+c^2x^2} \neq \vert x\vert \sqrt{1+\vert c \vert}$. Secondly $\Vert (x,cx)\Vert < \vert c \vert \implies \vert x \vert < \vert c \vert$ follows from a basic properties of the norm of vectors : If the norm of a vector $w = (w_1,...,w_n)$ is less than $\delta$ then each component's absolute value $\vert w_i \vert$ is also less than $\delta$. This is because a ball of radius $\delta$ is a subset of the square with side length $2\delta$ with the same center.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^{2}+c^{2}x^{2}} = \sqrt{x^{2}(1+c^{2})} = \sqrt{x^{2}}\sqrt{1+c^{2}} = |x|\sqrt{1+|c|^{2}}$, where $|x| = \sqrt{x^{2}}$....I see I made a mistake in what I wrote. :/, my apologies.  As for your second point, yes that was what I was inferring to. I didn't need to say reverse triangle inequality, in fact I shouldn't have and just stated the property of the norm as you mention. :)